# wp_query behaves strangely

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have a static frontpage and the blog part pointed to a page (with the link mylocalhost/news/) and a custom template called news ([code](http://pastie.org/5109324))

a custom permalink structure: `/%category%/%postname%/`

going here gives me this weird sql statement:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND (wp_posts.ID = '1829') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page' ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Obviously this will not get the posts I'm looking for. Why is this?

Comment: Try to print your wp_query arguments to see what is wrong with it. Sometimes in custom themes coders forget to use wp_reset_query() which reset all the args of your query.

Comment: That query is getting the data for the page you're using as a static frontpage, if you want to show some other posts you need to create a new query.

Comment: @Zekth - How do you print the query arguments?

Comment: @RichardM - Why is that? I don't think so because the id 1829 is not the static homepage.

Comment: Try using this : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var